# "DRY" javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, dry

I have a fair amount of functions like the ones below, all with some slight changes and querying different ids. Is there some way to concatenate this or will I just have to write them all out? Thanks.

```
function event() {
    var path = document.querySelector('#container #path'); 
    var length = path.getTotalLength(); 
    console.log(path.getTotalLength()); 
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
      'none';
    path.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    path.getBoundingClientRect();
    path.style.transition = path.style.WebkitTransition =
      'stroke-dashoffset 0.4s linear';
    path.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';

    document.getElementById("container").style.visibility = "visible";
};

function event2() {
    var path2 = document.querySelector('#container2 #path_2');
    var length = path2.getTotalLength();
    console.log(path2.getTotalLength());
    path2.style.transition = path2.style.WebkitTransition =
      'none';
    path2.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
    path2.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    path2.getBoundingClientRect();
    path2.style.transition = path2.style.WebkitTransition =
      'stroke-dashoffset 0.45s linear';
    path2.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';

    document.getElementById("container2").style.visibility = "visible";
};

function event3() {
    var path3 = document.querySelector('#container3 #path_3');
    var length = path3.getTotalLength();
    console.log(path3.getTotalLength());
    path3.style.transition = path3.style.WebkitTransition =
      'none';
    path3.style.strokeDasharray = length + ' ' + length;
    path3.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    path3.getBoundingClientRect();
    path3.style.transition = path3.style.WebkitTransition =
      'stroke-dashoffset 0.4s linear';
    path3.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';

    document.getElementById("container3").style.visibility = "visible";
};


window.setTimeout(function() {
    event();
}, 1);

window.setTimeout(function() {
    event2();
}, 550);

window.setTimeout(function() {
    event3();
}, 1100);
```

Comment: You typically DRY code by extracting the common parts, and the non-common parts become arguments to the extracted function(s).

Comment: MattBall is correct.  Give that a go and if you have further questions, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is generally a better place for this sort of thing.

Comment: The articles i've been reading haven't been able to help me solve this unique problem I have so thus I posted this question. So you're essentially telling me to google it and downvoting my question...

Comment: If the IDs shown in your code are the actual IDs you are using, then you could also think about using another way to identify them such as a class, which might then allow you to simplify your javascript.

Comment: Making them classes isnt going to help because all the containers need unique identifiers.

Comment: As you know, the argument passed to `querySelector` is a string. You can concatenate literal strings with variables, like so: `.querySelector('#container #path_' + some_variable_name);`. However, `id`s must be unique within the document, hence you don't need `#container` in the selector.

Answer (score 0):

If I have a series of nearly identical functions

```
function showNumber1() {
    window.alert("The number you wish to show is 1");
}
function showNumber2() {
    window.alert("The number you wish to show is 2");
    window.alert("Okay that's all");
}
function showNumber3() {
    window.alert("The number you wish to show is 3");
}
```

I can usually replace them with a single function, like

```
function showNumber(n) {
    window.alert("The number you wish to show is " + n);
    if (n == 2) {
        window.alert("Okay that's all");
    }
}
```

So, rewrite your functions into a single function containing the parts that stay the same, and use parameters and `if` statements to represent the parts that differ.

Also, you seem to be using IDs as if they are classes. Instead of having

```
<div id="path_1"> ... <div id="path_2"> ...
```

You could use a class

```
<div class="path"> ... <div class="path"> ...
```

and identify them in your javascript using `document.getElementsByClassName('path')[0]` and `document.getElementsByClassName('path')[1]` .

Comment: Okay, I'm going to try this, thanks, will let you know how it goes

Comment: I was unable to interpret your example and translate it to my own problem. Would have been nice to have you just flat out tell me how to do it so I could learn, but thanks a lot for the help anyways!

Comment: Why not post your attempt as another question.